# PHP void functions

Tags: php-7.1

PHP 7.1 will introduce the void function type.

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/void_return_type

In which cases is it useful to explicitly specify that a function is a "void" type instead of simply `return;` without any precision?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would be helpful to the developers working on the project for a few reasons.

- Provides a clear indication that the function does not return a value
- The above could equally apply to auto-generated docs
- Could be used for unit testing
- Could help prevent coding errors, where a developer accidentally tries to return, or expect, a value

Comment: An important use case is interfaces. It prevents implementations from returning a value and consumers of the interface accidentally relying on this.